# Implication of owned schemas for a user having db_owner privilege

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, security, permissions, users

[image]
Importance of "Schema owned by the user"?
The user is db_owner for the db. Is it required to select owned schemas?, or else it will own all the schemas as it is a db_owner? Please provide me a detail information for this particular topic. Thanks.

Comment: Where is SQL involved here?  Would you mind to name the RDBMS and the GUI you are using?

Comment: sql server 2008 r2

Answer (score 2):

Every schema must have an owner, which is a database principal (user or role) within the database.  The significance of the schema owner is that the owning principal has full control permissions.  Also, objects within the schema inherit the schema owner by default so the owning principal typically has control permissions on all database objects within the schema too.   Consequently, ownership chaining is usually determined by the schema owner.

You don't need to select owned schemas for a user.  The UI simply provides the schema list for informational convenience since you can't drop a user if they own a schema.  To drop an user that owns a schema, you'll need to first drop the schema or change the owner (a.k.a. authorization) of the schema to a different principal.